# How to Convert this dynamic content in to an javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Hello everyone i would like to do this. I have a javascript variable which has this kind of value `[section][row][/row][/section]` I would like to convert this into an javascript array. do anyone has any clue about this. I just like an array like 
            [0]=>[section]
            [1]=>[row]
            [2]=>[/row]
            [3]=>[/section]
Please Help me to do this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean that you would like to put those values in to an array, as individual strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var tags = '[section][row][/row][/section]'.match(/\[\/?\w+]/g);
tags; // ["[section]", "[row]", "[/row]", "[/section]"]
```

Comment: Thank you. My Problem is sloved by your comments.